# How do I compile a self made header in C with gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

So I wanto to compile a program that has included these headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "teclas_tictac.h"
```

The header `teclas_tictac.h` has prototypes for functions in `teclas_tictac.c` file.

How do I do that?

I usually do `gcc myprogram.c -o myprogram`.

Thanks

Comment: You need `-I` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to get too technical, but the function implementations is what needs to be assembled, converted to object code and finally linked, the header file is not used directly in the compilation process, its contents are simply copied to where you use the `#include` directive.

So what you need for the compilation process is the `.c` file not the header file.

```
gcc myprogram.c teclas_tictac.c -o myprogram
```

You can also include [warning flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) in the process which can help detect problems you may otherwise miss.

Here are some of the more commonly used:

```
gcc myprogram.c teclas_tictac.c -o myprogram -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

Comment: @martiwg, glad to help, I added a mention to the teclas_tictac.c  flle to your question, since it's related to the problem.